# How to find difference between chrome & android native browser

Tags: php, browser, user-agent

Please help me on this

I am getting below as user agent in chrome

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; P470 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.83 Safari/537.36
```

where as in native browser i'm getting below as user agent

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; Micromax P470 Build/KOT49H)  AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36;
```

everything is similar except version/version_code

As we can see through "version/version_code" we can differ it but issue is it differs device to device

for example i'm  not getting version/version_code in Samsung s series device

Its time consuming to check each and every different type of device.

Is there any dynamic way to check whether browser is native browser or chrome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: … and this is why user agent detection is considered to be a terrible idea. Use feature detection instead.

Answer (score 0):

For native browser in android (webview), You can look for the

> The Android 4.4 (KitKat) Chromium-based WebView adds Chrome/*version* to the user agent string.

So, In the above example, `Version/4.0` will tell you that it is a native web view.

> If you’re attempting to differentiate between the WebView and Chrome for Android, you should look for the presence of the Version/*X.X* string in the WebView user-agent string. Don’t rely on the specific Chrome version number (for example, 30.0.0.0) as the version numbers changes with each release.

Refer: [User Agent Strings](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent)

Comment: Yes i'm not relying on number instead  i'm checking "version/" as i have mentioned in example only version is the difference but for Samsung devices version doesn't come , so its failing in that case. Samsung is the one case.. might be different in some other case.So i'm looking for dynamic solution

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant the version of the chrome tag. Can I see what the User agent for the Samsung device is?

Comment: everything is similar except "SamsungBrowser/version"

Comment: I think that we can assume that `SamsungBrowser/version` is for samsung's native webview. Can you filter based on that? And it is possible that User Agent can be spoofed. So might I suggest that you look for an alternative parameter to check the device.

Comment: Yes currently i'm doing the same but cant assume that same thing will come as user agent for all devices. As you can see in example there is no other separation parameter to identify.

Comment: If you are facing this issue only with Samsung, then you can do something like this,

If User agent contains `Version` or `SamsungBrowser/version` then it means that it is the native browser. Else, it is Chrome for mobile. 


Making sure the UserAgent is from a mobile can be done with `mobile` in the user agent string.